# Is this a problem with the Code Optimizer in the Qwik.js framework?

Tags: javascript, typescript, qwik

I'm getting an error that ChatGPT definitely thinks is coming from the code optimizer of Qwik.js, and if that's the case there's unfortunately nothing I can do to debug the issue.

```
const drawImageTask = useVisibleTask$(() => {
    const canvas = canvasSignal.value;
    if (canvas) {
      const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      const img = new Image();
      img.src = mapProps.imageUrl;
      img.onload = async () => {
        const canvasSize = calculateCanvasSize(img); // < ------------------------- causes error

function calculateCanvasSize(image: HTMLImageElement) {
    const aspectRatio = image.width / image.height;
    const canvasWidth = window.innerWidth;
    const canvasHeight = canvasWidth / aspectRatio;
    return [canvasWidth, canvasHeight];
  }
```

12:02:14 AM [vite] Internal server error: Cannot read properties of null (reading '0')
Plugin: vite-plugin-qwik
File: G:/projects/websites/LoreCoords/Qwik Basic Template/src/components/map/map.tsx
at createRollupError2 (G:\projects\websites\LoreCoords\Qwik Basic Template\node_modules@builder.io\qwik\optimizer.cjs:1624:38)
at G:\projects\websites\LoreCoords\Qwik Basic Template\node_modules@builder.io\qwik\optimizer.cjs:2166:49
at Array.forEach ()
at G:\projects\websites\LoreCoords\Qwik Basic Template\node_modules@builder.io\qwik\optimizer.cjs:2164:23
at Object.transform (G:\projects\websites\LoreCoords\Qwik Basic Template\node_modules@builder.io\qwik\optimizer.cjs:1314:9)
at TransformContext.transform (G:\projects\websites\LoreCoords\Qwik Basic Template\node_modules@builder.io\qwik\optimizer.cjs:2204:27)
at Object.transform (file:///G:/projects/websites/LoreCoords/Qwik%20Basic%20Template/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-79892de8.js:43387:44)
at async loadAndTransform (file:///G:/projects/websites/LoreCoords/Qwik%20Basic%20Template/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-79892de8.js:41105:29)

Comment: It is returning null instead of array

Comment: The image isn't null, and the width and height all have properties. Everything seems fine unless I try to rebuild with calculateCanvasSize, when I get that error dump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was down to the fact that these methods were part of a component. The function definition was incorrect for calculateCanvasSize. Instead it should have been:

```
const calculateCanvasSize = $((image: HTMLImageElement) => {  
    console.log(image.width + "= width" + image.height + "= image.height");    
     const aspectRatio = image.width / image.height;
     const canvasWidth = window.innerWidth;
     const canvasHeight = canvasWidth / aspectRatio;
     
    return [canvasWidth, canvasHeight];
    
  });
```